# Sync data between two Oracle db tables

Tags: .net, oracle

I have to sync data from one Oracle db1 table tb1 to another db2's table tbl2. To keep simple, I can truncate data on db2 tbl2 and then copy all the data from db1 tbl1. Both tables have the same data column structure.

Since two tables are on different databases, I am thinking to use a media file like txt or xml as a media. I export data from db1 tbl1 to the media first, and then insert data from the media like inserting data from a bulk of text.

This simple project will be a console app in .Net(I am using VS 2008). I prefer to make this app generic so that only configuration settings are: two connection strings, and two table names. I'll use text file or xml as media to avoid to provide detail information about data types for each column. I am not sure if there is API or classes available to export data and import data for Oracle db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget .Net. Use [DataPump](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/toc.htm) or old imp/exp.

The problem with XML/text formatting is what do you do with complex datatypes (like, for example, XML). You'd spend a massive amount of time developing and testing a generic solution that correctly escapes data, caters for BLOBs and other exotic datatypes...

Comment: A database link would be an option too

Answer (score 1):

Why reinvent the wheel?  Oracle has bi-directional replication.

Comment: The console app will be scheduled job to sync data. Now I don't have permission to add a job on Oracle db to do bi-direction replication.

Comment: You're not using functionality that you may have paid thousands of dollars for in order to manually write your own version.  Well, sir, good luck.